# Recursive calls to a server using AJAX not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, recursion

I am developing a web-application on File Management System in which I have to access various directories on my system and list them on my web page. I have used AJAX to make rest calls to the server. I have created a rest-controller to handle the requests.

I am encountering a problem in the execution of a java-script function which I have to call recursively on the basis of a counter. The function is to navigate backwards in a directory. If the value of count is zero, I will display the result on the web page, else I will recursively call the function. The function works as expected in Chrome but not in IE-11.

I want to make multiple calls to the server based on the counter value. Hence I am calling the function recursively, but the call to the server is made only once. This problem occurs in IE-11. In Chrome, it works perfectly.

The function is:

```
function gobackDir(count) {
    var back_count = count;             
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://neha:8080/myServer/goback",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function($event) {
        if ($event.currentTarget.readyState==4 && $event.currentTarget.status==200) {   
            back_count--;
            if (back_count > 0) {
                gobackDir(back_count);
            }
            else {
                var server_response = JSON.parse($event.currentTarget.response);                        
                    set_currentDirectory(server_response);                      
                    set_directoryContent(server_response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a screenshoot of your console ? (F12) may be it's a cross-origin problem

Comment: make sure that your page has url like this http://neha:8080/../page.html

Comment: @Elheni Mokhles: Sorry, I am unable to upload the image. The url is correct. I used the url to make rest calls to the server directly from the browser, and it is working fine, also its working in chrome. The problem in IE is that the request is not sent multiple times. Its sent only once.

Comment: try to use $.ajax (jquery)

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you need to bust the cache:

```
var bustCache = (new Date()).getTime();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://neha:8080/myServer/goback?" + bustCache,true);
```